# C# Flaten a nested list to list of different object for display in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm having an issue presenting my nested collection in a WPF Datagrid.
bellow is the code that is giving me the desired result, but I wonder if it is possible to make it simpler?

```
public async Task LoadRecepi(short id)
    {
        Recepi = await _recepiDataService.Get(id);

        var flat = new List<FlatRecepi1>();
        foreach (var step in Recepi.Step)
        {
            flat.Add(new FlatRecepi1 { 
                RecepiId = step.RecepiId,
                StepId = step.SPTagId,
                Activity = step.Activity,
                PVTagName = step.PVTag.Name
            });  
            foreach (var node in step.Nodes)
            {
                flat.Add(new FlatRecepi1
                {
                    StepId = node.SPTagId,
                    SPTagName = node.SPTag.Name,
                    PVTagName = node.PVTag.Name
                });
            }
        }           

    }
```

thankyou so much for your help.

```
public class FlatRecepi1
{        
    public short RecepiId { get; set; }
    public short StepId { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public short NodeId { get; set; }
    public string StepName { get; set; }
    public string PVTagName { get; set; }
    public string SPTagName { get; set; }
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You can use `Select` or `SelectMany` to avoid using `foreach` loops, but still need to map all fields, and it can be more complicated then your current code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski is right; given that the two levels of FlatRecepi1 is instantiated differently (from the `step` and from the `node`) those code lines cannot be reused. So basically you cannot simplify it. (Had the `node` and the `step` been of the same type or one of them inherited from the other the `new FlatRecepi1`-part could be reused.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) and [`Enumerable.Prepend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netcore-3.1).

The following code will project out each step's nodes into a collection of `FlatRecepi1` and then prepend the `FlatRecepi1` corresponding to the step at the *start* of the collection. Finally, the `SelectMany` flattens this "collection of collections" into a single list. This should give you the same ordering as the current code.

```
var flat = Recepi.Step.SelectMany(step => 
   step.Nodes.Select(node => new FlatRecepi1 { 
       StepId = node.SPTagId, 
       SPTagName = node.SPTag.Name,
       PVTagName = node.PVTag.Name 
   }).Prepend(new FlatRecepi1 { 
       RecepiId = step.RecepiId,
       StepId = step.SPTagId,
       Activity = step.Activity,
       PVTagName = step.PVTag.Name,
   })
).ToList();
```

If `Prepend` is not available to you because you are using an older framework, we can achieve the same with [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var flat = Recepi.Step.SelectMany(step => 
   new [] { 
      new FlatRecepi1 { 
        RecepiId = step.RecepiId,
        StepId = step.SPTagId,
        Activity = step.Activity,
        PVTagName = step.PVTag.Name,
      }
   }.Concat(
      step.Nodes.Select(node => new FlatRecepi1 { 
        StepId = node.SPTagId, 
        SPTagName = node.SPTag.Name,
        PVTagName = node.PVTag.Name 
      }) 
   )
).ToList();
```